# I am completing kmeans cluster model and when trying to scale the data it picks up the column name for the first column and returns error

Tags: r, scale

I am working to complete kmeans cluster in R.   When I try to scale the data I get an error message "Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric".   I assume it is picking up the heading of the first column

```
dftest <- scale(test)
```

this should be easy but for some reason getting this error.   Can anyone help me get past this simple first step?   Thanks!

the data sample is test and below:

```
structure(list(PIN = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e"), class = "factor"), v1 = c(0.8, 0.36, 0.21, 0.84, 0.43
), v2 = c(0.87, 0.01, 0.56, 0.75, 0.98), v3 = c(0.48, 0.13, 0.26, 
0.34, 0.83)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because there are columns that are not `numeric`

```
scale(test)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Check the `str(test)`

```
str(test)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ PIN: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ v1 : num  0.8 0.36 0.21 0.84 0.43
 $ v2 : num  0.87 0.01 0.56 0.75 0.98
 $ v3 : num  0.48 0.13 0.26 0.34 0.83
```

The 'PIN" is a `factor` column.  Just remove that by negative indexing on the column position

```
scale(test[-1])
        v1         v2         v3
1  0.9766119  0.6177883  0.2687578
2 -0.6032015 -1.6334743 -1.0377036
3 -1.1417742 -0.1937133 -0.5524465
4  1.1202313  0.3036587 -0.2538268
5 -0.3518675  0.9057405  1.5752191
attr(,"scaled:center")
   v1    v2    v3 
0.528 0.634 0.408 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
       v1        v2        v3 
0.2785139 0.3820079 0.2678992 
>
```

or if there are more columns, subset dynamically

```
scale(Filter(is.numeric, test))
        v1         v2         v3
1  0.9766119  0.6177883  0.2687578
2 -0.6032015 -1.6334743 -1.0377036
3 -1.1417742 -0.1937133 -0.5524465
4  1.1202313  0.3036587 -0.2538268
5 -0.3518675  0.9057405  1.5752191
attr(,"scaled:center")
   v1    v2    v3 
0.528 0.634 0.408 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
       v1        v2        v3 
0.2785139 0.3820079 0.2678992
```

---

Or with `collapse`, get the numeric columns with `num_vars`, and apply fast 'scale' function `fscale`

```
library(collapse)
fscale(num_vars(test))
          v1         v2         v3
1  0.9766119  0.6177883  0.2687578
2 -0.6032015 -1.6334743 -1.0377036
3 -1.1417742 -0.1937133 -0.5524465
4  1.1202313  0.3036587 -0.2538268
5 -0.3518675  0.9057405  1.5752191
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and this works great!!

Comment: @DataScienceDave Thanks.  If it works, can you please consider to accept solution.